# What is an acceptable way to implement "UpdateDomainObject" method in an Assembler dealing with Data Transfer Objects, & Entities in C# ASP.NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, entity, design-patterns, dto, n-tier-architecture

I am writing a "Domain Object" --> "Assembler" --> "Data Transfer Object" (DTO) pattern into my shared library to allow the presentation tier and the service layer to communicate through DTO's.  I have avoided any shared interfaces to allow course grained aggregation in the DTO.  I have a solid grasp in the "CreateDTO" methods, but am wondering how one implements UpdateDomainObject(DTO dto) methods in the Assembler in C#.  I am considering the following structure to simplify my code:

```
public class SomeAssembler
{
public static SomeDTO CreateDTO(SomeDomainObject obj)
{
dto.Property1 = obj.Property1;
...
}
//METHOD IN QUESTION:
public static void UpdateDomainObject(SomeDTO dto, SomeDomainObject obj)
    {obj.Property1 = dto.Property1 ...}
}
```

The reason I include a Domain Object parameter in the method is to allow code like below:

```
//Presentation Layer Code (PL signifies presentation layer type)
ContactPL : IContact //(IContact is an Entity library contract shared across layers in separate DLL)
{
#region Properties
//Note Mixed Types, so params not an option
public int Id {get;set}
public String FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
public Address address {get;set;}
#endregion

#region Methods
//METHOD IN QUESTION:
public void GetContact(int id)
{
ContactDTO dto = ContactService.GetContactbyId(id);
ContactAssembler.UpdateContact(dot, this);
}

// Other Methods...

#endregion
}
```

Please note the methods marked above as "//METHOD IN QUESTION:".  My question, "Is this structure acceptable and / or are there any concerns with writing the code this way?"

I know Java deals with these issues as follows.  I want to make sure that My Assembler method for "UpdateDomainObject" and its inclusion in the Presentation Layer model object would be acceptable or ideal.  If not, any ideas for better ways to skin the cat?

Java Example - Assembler Method for Update from DTO (only for comparison - Answer in C# terms please):

```
public static void updateCustomer(CustomerDTO dto) {
Customer target = null;
for(Customer c: Domain.customers) {
if (dto.name.equals(c.getName())) {
target = c;
break;
}
}
if (target != null) {
target.setAddress(dto.address);
target.setPhone(dto.phone);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including both the DTO and Domain Object in the 'Update' method, you are forcing the presentation layer to deal with both DTO's and Domain Objects.

It would be simpler to have the presentation layer deal with only the kind of objects that are relevant to it, whether that be DTO's, Domain Objects or a separate presentation layer specific class of objects, and let the assembler take care of the translations.

Your Java example is a good example of isolating this kind of translation to the assembler.

The benefits of this kind of isolation is a reduction in coupling in your code, which in turn makes your code more flexible (I.e. easier to change) as well as reduction in complexity which I'm turn makes your code easier to maintain.

Comment: So how would this code look in C#?  To add more detail the applicaiton I am developing is a 3 thier appliciaton with a WCF layer in between the Presentation Layer and the Domain Layer.  The "shared entity library" will be used in the Data Access Layer(Repository), Business Logic Layer, and I am considering the Presentaiton Layer as well.  Reason: the whole stack at this point is ASP.NET.  I can use the ChannelFactory<T> to leverage binary encoding and the local library to reduce messaging overhead.  I get reasons to building off the DTO's (which carry DataContractAttribute).

Comment: On the Domain side objects will be similar to example above but layer specific classes will be ContactBLL and ContactDAL.  Each will have different code in the "GetContact" methods.  Noteably, DAL will have ADO.Net and will be called by BLL code to hydrate the object from an SQL database.